# creating a vector of pointers that point to more vectors

Tags: c++, vector, pointers

I am trying to create a vector that contains pointers, each pointer points to another vector of a type `Cell` which I have made using a struct.
The for loop below allows me to let the user define how many elements there are in the vector of pointers. Here's my code:

```
vector< vector<Cell>* >  vEstore(selection);
for (int t=0; t<selection; t++)
{
    vEstore[t] = new vector<Cell>; 
    vEstore[t]->reserve(1000);
}
```

This, I think, gives me a vector of pointers to destination vectors of the type `Cell`.
This compiles but I'm now trying to `push_back` onto the destination vectors and can't see how to do it.

Since the destination vector is of the type Cell which is made from a type as follows:

```
struct Cell
{
    unsigned long long lr1;
    unsigned int cw2;
};
```

I can't work out how to `push_back` onto this destination vector with 2 values?

I was thinking ...

```
binpocket[1]->lr1.push_back(10);
binpocket[1]->cw2.push_back(12);
```

As I thought this would dereference the pointer at `binpocket[1]` revealing the destination array values, then address each element in turn.
But it doesn't compile.

can anyone help
...but this only has one value and doesn't compile anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Cell cell = { 10, 12 };
binpocket[1]->push_back(cell);
```

Alternatively, you can give your struct a constructor.

```
struct Cell
{
    Cell() {}
    Cell(unsigned long long lr1, unsigned int cw2)
        : lr1(lr1), cw2(cw2)
    {
    }

    unsigned long long lr1;
    unsigned int cw2;
};
```

Then you could do

```
binpocket[1]->push_back(Cell(10, 12));
```

Note that `long long` is non-standard (yet), but is a generally accepted extension.

Comment: This is probably a really stupid question but why do you have the constructor twice, once empty?

Comment: If you provide no constructors, the compiler will create an empty default (i.e. parameter-less) constructor for you. That means you can do `Cell cell;`. By providing a custom constructor, the compiler won't create the default constructor for you. That's why I provided it. You don't have to do that, if you don't want to do `Cell cell;`.

Answer (score 3):

Give your cell a constructor:

```
struct Cell
{
    unsigned long long lr1;
    unsigned int cw2;

    Cell( long long lv, int iv ) : lr1(lv), cw2(iv ) {}
};
```

You can now say things like:

```
binpocket[1]->push_back( Cell( 10, 12 ) );
```

BTW, note that long long is not standard C++.